# Prerequisite to use Heapster API on Kubernetes

Tags: api, kubernetes, heapster

What are the prerequisite steps to be done, apart from starting the service of Heapster, before I use Heapster API to retrieve the metrics related Kubernetes ? Thanks.

Comment: Heapster service is running and I can see it in Kubernetes dashboard. I also could see the list of Heapster APIs through swagger-ui.

Comment: When I try to get the list of metrics
https://<url>/api/v1/namespaces/<NAMESPACE-NAME>/pods/<POD-NAME>metrics

I am getting the following result

{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {},
  "code": 404
}

Comment: what version are you using? there has been a lot of changes over time and you need to make sure the version you use is suitable for the version of K8s you use.